# CKEditor 4: Pasting in div tag converts to p tag (Chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, ckeditor4.x

I am running CKEditor 4.11 with the standard install on a Mac. When I copy and paste a simple div tag it always converts it to a p tag.

UPDATE: This appears to be a problem in **Chrome** but not FireFox.

I have disabled ACF using `config.allowedContent = true` but it doesn't help. My config is empty of any extra plugins or rules. I CAN paste `<div>test</div>` into source and then copy and paste it fine at that point from within the rendered (non-source) view, but any div copy/pasted from a rendered HTML web page will just get converted to a p tag in the editor.

Other tags are also stripped when pasting from a web page. For example, any `<span>` is removed. Before turning off ACF, I went down the route of setting `config.extraAllowedContent` (span(*)). While that correctly worked when pasting in raw source, it did nothing when pasting in copied web content.

Sample between Chrome & FireFox when copying "simple span" from a web page where the markup is `<span class="foo">Simple span</span>`

Chrome (with ACF disabled or when allowing span(*)
    `<p>Simple span</p>`

Firefox
    `<p><span class="foo">Simple span</span></p>`

Thanks for any assist!